# How do I install a driver on an android device using android studio?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gps, driver

I want to install a driver so I can use my phone's USB port to connect to a GPS. I do not know how I have to install the drivers in the mobile. As USB connector I use a CP210x UART Bridge.

Answer (score 0):

Since Android Compatibility test includes a 'GPS', your phone should have a GPS and you would like to use the GPS included in your device, rather than hooking up an extra one. Even if you use incompatible device that doesn't includes GPS, you cannot just simply 'install' the driver on your phone since the driver is embedded in the kernel on android.